# Aggregating data by column in array

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's say I have the following data:

```
gp_id | p_id
------|-------
1     | 123
2     | 432
2     | 222
```

For the purposes of business logic I have to transform that into this:

```
gp_id | p_ids
------|----------
1     | {123}
2     | {432,222}
```

I tried to do something like this (actually, I understand that this is the wrong approach, but still):

```
select gp_id, array(
    select p_id from cte
    ) as p_ids
from cte
```

And, predictably enough, it returns the following:

```
gp_id | p_ids
------|--------------
1     | {123,432,222}
2     | {123,432,222}
2     | {123,432,222}
```

Could anyone please help me with this?
And yes, as a matter of fact, I'm using this in a series of common table expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
select c1.gp_id, array(
    select p_id from cte c2 where c2.gp_id = c1.gp_id
    ) as p_ids
from cte c1 group by c1.gp_id;
```

OR

```
select gp_id, group_concat(p_id) p_ids
from cte group by gp_id;
```

Comment: thank you, I learned a lot with your help! I had a very little practice with sql, and you showed a great way that expanded my understanding.

Comment: Sure. Welcome. Optionally you can also use group_concat.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you please give me a hint about how to put into array only distinct values?

Comment: Just add `distinct` before `p_id`

Comment: Sure buddy... :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `array_agg` :

```
select
    gp_id, array_agg(p_id) as p_ids
from cte
group by gp_id
```

Comment: that's absolutely great and clean solution, thank you very much!